# how many else ifs can i use , last else not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

What can I do to inprove this script? The last else if wont work for some reason I have tried a lot to get it to work and it just wont.

```
var selectedDntTyp = $("#donationTypDD");
if (selectedDntTyp.length > 0)
  var DropInitValue = selectedDntTyp.val();
if(DropInitValue == '1'){
  $(".Notify_brick").show();
  $("#in_memory_input").show();
} else if(DropInitValue == '3'){
  $(".Notify_brick").show();
  $("#on_behalf_input").show();
}
$("#donationTypDD").change(function(){
  if($(this).val()=="1") {
    $(".Notify_brick").slideDown();
    $("#in_memory_input").slideDown();
  } else if($(this).val()=="3") {
    $(".Notify_brick").slideDown();
    $("#on_behalf_input").slideDown();
  } else if ($(this).val=="1"||$(this).val!="3") {
    $(".Notify_brick").slideUp();
    $("#on_behalf_input").slideUp();
  } else if ($(this).val=="3"||$(this).val!="1") {
    $(".Notify_brick").slideUp();
    $("#in_memory_input").slideUp();
  } else if ($(this).val!="1"||$(this).val!="3") {
    $(".Notify_brick").slideUp();
    $("#in_memory_input").slideUp();
    $("#on_behalf_input").slideUp();
  }
})
```

Comment: Statement 3 & 4 of `$("#donationTypDD").change()` will never run because they are handled by statement 1 & 2. Also, use `var currentVal = $(this).val()` instead of repeatedly calling `$(this).val()`

Comment: The title should be changed. The question is asking what is wrong with the code. And the correct answer is to the question. Should I just do a normal edit?

Comment: so basically 3 & 4 will never work ?

Comment: @Glenn #3 will catch everything not caught in your first 2 if statements. 4 and 5 will never run.

Answer (score 3):

Replace  `$(this).val` into `$(this).val()`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing ().  Change all your $(this).val ----> $(this).val()

Comment: You are a little late... Krish said the same thing 8 minutes ago.